# How to a return an array of data after joining tables in Knex?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I have three tables I need to join: theaters, movies_theaters, movies. I need to return all data from the three tables but movies_theaters and movies are inside an array in theaters.

What I have so far:

```
const theatersMoviesJoin = knex('theaters as t')
  .join('movies_theaters as mt', 't.theater_id', 'mt.theater_id')
  .join('movies as m', 'm.movie_id', 'mt.movie_id');

const getAllTheaters = () => theatersMoviesJoin.select('t.*', 'm.*', 'mt.*');
```

The result looks like:

```json
{
  "theater_id": 1,
  "name": "Regal City Center",
  "address_line_1": "801 C St.",
  "address_line_2": "",
  "city": "Vancouver",
  "state": "WA",
  "zip": "98660",
  "true": null,
  "movie_id": 1,
  "title": "Spirited Away",
  "runtime_in_minutes": 125,
  "rating": "PG",
  "description": "Chihiro and her parents are moving to a small Japanese town in the countryside, much to Chihiro's dismay. On the way to their new home, Chihiro's father makes a wrong turn and drives down a lonely one-lane road which dead-ends in front of a tunnel. Her parents decide to stop the car and explore the area. They go through the tunnel and find an abandoned amusement park on the other side, with its own little town...",
  "image_url": "https://imdb-api.com/images/original/MV5BMjlmZmI5MDctNDE2YS00YWE0LWE5ZWItZDBhYWQ0NTcxNWRhXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTMxODk2OTU@._V1_Ratio0.6791_AL_.jpg",
  "created_at": "2021-03-08T19:07:31.130Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-03-08T19:07:31.130Z",
  "is_showing": true
}
```

What I need it to look like:

```json
{
  "theater_id": 1,
  "name": "Regal City Center",
  "address_line_1": "801 C St.",
  "address_line_2": "",
  "city": "Vancouver",
  "state": "WA",
  "zip": "98660",
  "created_at": "2021-02-23T20:48:13.335Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-02-23T20:48:13.335Z",
  "movies": [
    {
      "movie_id": 1,
      "title": "Spirited Away",
      "runtime_in_minutes": 125,
      "rating": "PG",
      "description": "Chihiro...",
      "image_url": "https://imdb-api.com...",
      "created_at": "2021-02-23T20:48:13.342Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-02-23T20:48:13.342Z",
      "is_showing": false,
      "theater_id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done with `Knex` (which is only a query builder), you will need to do it manually.

```js
const flatList = [{ ... }, { ... }];

function groupByTheater(flatList) {
  const groupedList = flatList.reduce((result, row) => {
    result[row.theater_id] = result[row.theater_id] || {
      theater_id: row.theater_id,
      name: row.name,
      address_line_1: row.address_line_1,
      address_line_2: row.address_line_2,
      city: row.city,
      state: row.state,
      zip: row.zip,
      created_at: row.created_at,
      updated_at: row.updated_at,
      movies: [],
    };

    result[row.theater_id].movies.push({
      movie_id: row.movie_id,
      title: row.title,
      runtime_in_minutes: row.runtime_in_minutes,
      rating: row.rating,
      description: row.description,
      image_url: row.image_url,
      created_at: row.created_at,
      updated_at: row.updated_at,
      is_showing: row.is_showing,
      theater_id: row.theater_id,
    });

    return result;
  }, {});

  return Object.values(groupedList);
}

const groupedList = groupByTheater(flatList);
```